# Drivers on Websites Other Than Manufacturer

Tags: laptop, drivers

I was wondering if it is safe to download a driver for your PC from a web site other than the manufacturer.  My initial assumption is no, but I'm sure there are reputable sites.  So is it safe, and what is a good site to choose from?

Thanks.

Comment: Go for the official websites that produces these products. Like graphic card drivers from nvidia,ati,intel. wifi drivers from intel, broadcom.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would ever even have the desire to go to a 3rd party site rather than the manufacturer?